# I need circuit help with headphone amplifier 'thump' and other issues

Tags: amplifier

This is my first post and I have a million questions. I hope some kind souls out there will not mind my noobness and be able to guide me any way they can.

Firstly, I have a headphone amplifier circuit that runs off 9V using the TDA2822M chip. The amplifier works fine as a mono amp (yes I know class D is no good for headphones) but that is all I need for my purposes.

My question is in regards to the nasty 'thump' I get when I switch on the amp.

Is there some kind of capacitor/resistor combination that I can use on the input voltage that powers the circuit on slow enough to minimise the thump in the earphones?

Secondly, I have redesigned and enclosed a digital wireless transmitter/receiver, connected it to a headphone amplifier and built myself a nice little cheap digital earphone beltpack system. My issue is with the digital noise that is part of the circuit. I also have a great deal of noise when nothing is connected to the transmitter input. I know this probably sounds a bit vague but unless I post pictures and describe in great detail the whole setup (which I can do) it may or may not help with the issue.

I have powered the transmitter circuit with a linear regulated 5V power supply. I have used a 10k 1:1 transformer on the audio input. I am suspecting its a shielding issue somewhere. Any advice or questions for clarification will be much appreciated. Please let me know any specifics you might require to be able to answer this question. I know there's probably so many variables and I am not experienced enough to know where to start more than what 'google' has suggested.

Comment: Regarding TDA2822 "thump", it is not something which can easily be avoided without adding extra circuitry. Different component values might get you a different "thump" but a "thump" nonetheless. In mode fancy amplifiers the headphone jack is only connected a few seconds **after** power on so the amplifiers have had time to settle (that causes the thump).

Comment: I'm curious why you think a Class D amplifier is 'no good' for headphones.

Comment: You will have to give  a proper description of what you did (components used) with the wireless gadget including links to datasheets. The noise might simply be a property of the chosen components.

Comment: @replete Most class D amps have outputs like a bridge amplifier, meaning none of the signals to the speaker is ground. In case of a stereo setup, you cannot share the ground line which is how almost all headphones are wired. I do believe though that you could still use a class D stereo amp with headphones. By using only use one of the two outputs and adding an AC coupling capacitor. Similar to standard analog power amps. Not every class D amp might like this though.

Comment: I can draw some schematics and take some pictures asap. The digital transmitter/receiver is proprietary technology so there will be no info online for it. I am more than happy to add some components to the voltage before it hits the headphone amp. I read somewhere that a cap in series will slow the initial voltage to the amp but I've looked everywhere and cant find the exact values neccessary. Capacitor values are still something I need to learn about. @Bimpelrekkie, you are correct about the class D amp thing. I've looked for a decent workaround but looks like its far too complicated

Comment: *I read somewhere that a cap in series will slow the initial voltage to the amp* In series with the supply perhaps ? I think that is still a "kludge" solution. A better solution would be to short the headphone output at power up, for example using an NMOS. There are also "plop-free" (headphone) amp. ICs, it might be much easier to use one of those instead of TDA2822.

Comment: Will that damage the amp in any way by shorting the output? Do you have a circuit I could perhaps try?

Comment: Don't (almost) all phones and such use class D or similar amplifiers for the headphones? (power efficiency)? Or is that just for the onboard speakers?

Comment: The old TDA2822 is simple and was designed to produce a THUMP at power-up. Today there are many little power amps that are thump-free.

Answer (score 1):

The TDA2822 is NOT CLASS-D, it is the normal class-AB. It is fairly noisy.
It is cheap and old and is obsolete today so it does not have "pop-free" circuits used in modern amplifiers.

Comment: The cheap old TDA2822M has two amplifiers in it but is used as a mono amplifier so maybe it is BRIDGE connected that puts DC on a headphone plug since a bridge has no ground. When used as a stereo amplifier then each output is capacitor-coupled and each - input has a large capacitor to ground that probably charges slowly preventing a thump.

Answer (score 0):

First up, this is NOT a class D amp. Class D is a "digital" amp. The chip you are using is a fairly standard linear op amp, albeit with slightly higher current output than usual.

The thump you are getting is unavoidable for the circuit you have. It is caused by the the output of the amp settling as the power is applied. You will not eliminate it with DC blocking caps, etc.

The only way to stop it would be with extra circuitry. One way would be a dual relay or similar to connect the headphones, which is only turned on a second or so after power up. The powering of the relay can be achieved with a fairly simple CR circuit and a driver transistor.

There are also other designs that have a MUTE pin, which you should make inactive after power up. This still requires you to derive a suitable control signal from somewhere. There may also be chips that will do this that have the anti-thump stuff built-in, I didn't search. But the design you have cannot be fixed without some modification.

Answer (score -3):

I am not familiar with your exact situation, but it seems to be related to the fact that one side of your headphone is grounded, while the amplifier output floats at some potential different from ground.

Therefore, consider using an output transformer to isolate the DC floating voltage of the amplifier from the grounded output circuit.

If you really want to educate and empower yourself, consider building your own transformer.  It is not as hard as the big boyz make it sound.

Back in the day, we used vacuum tube amplifiers.  They used high voltage.  It was possible to save money on a transformer by wiring the headphone between the vacuum tube and the high voltage supply.   As a California board-registered EE, there are some forms of death that are professionally embarrassing for us, so do as I teach you, not as I did when I was young and smart.